# Querying for html embed element in Chrome returns anonymous function

Tags: google-chrome, xpath

I am querying the following HTML content

```
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <embed id="embed1" src="../support/test3.mp3" autostart="true" style="width:150px; height:150px" alt="fish">
            <noembed id="noembed1">Sound of a fish</noembed>

        <embed id="embed1a" src="../support/test3.mp3" autostart="TRUE" style="width:150px; height:150px" alt="fish">
            <noembed id="noembed1a">Sound of a fish</noembed>

    </body></html>
```

with the following XPATH query

```
var nodes = document.evaluate("/html[1]/body[1]/embed[1]", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
var node = nodes.iterateNext(); 
console.log(node);
```

This returns the anonymous function.

```
function anonymous()
```

but where as Firefox returns the embed element.

How do I get the embed node in chrome?

Comment: Why are trying to use `XPath`? You can simply use `var nodes = document.getElementById("embed1");`

Comment: because I only have the XPATH returned by other component. I need to get to the element using XPATH so that I can do the other operations on it.

Comment: Actually your code returns required web element as it should, not a function. Where do you get this `XPath` from?

Comment: I am actually getting "function anonymous()" printed for this javascript.  to reproduce run https://jsfiddle.net/qep543cb/ on chrome and see your browser console.

Comment: This might be `Chrome` issue. Simply try `alert(node)` or `console.log(node.getAttribute("id"));` to make sure that it is `embed` webelement

Answer (score 0):

Chrome fixed this defect https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=708724 
I verified in night build, and it works.